# Help me plot this function

Tags: plotting

f[k] = -(1/2)^k - ((1/4) (1 - sqrt[5]))^k/sqrt[5] + ((1/4) (1 + sqrt[5]))^k/sqrt[5]
(and also f[k] = 0 when k = 1,2)

I need to make a lineplot of this function in k = 3,4,5,... ,20.

1. why this does not plot my grpah?
2. how to plot a graph of this function? (input is integer)
3. how to deal with exceptions k=1, k=2?

[image]

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88571/8253

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[k_] = -(1/2)^k - ((1/4) (1 - Sqrt[5]))^k/Sqrt[5] + 
    ((1/4) (1 + Sqrt[5]))^k/Sqrt[5];

Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[Re@f[k]], {k, 4/5, 15}],
 DiscretePlot[f[k], {k, 1, 15}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15.5}, Automatic},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
f[k_] = -(1/2)^k - ((1/4) (1 - Sqrt[5]))^k/
    Sqrt[5] + ((1/4) (1 + Sqrt[5]))^k/Sqrt[5];
ListPlot[Table[f[k], {k, 3, 20}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
 MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: ok, so I changed my mind and re-stating my previous comment. Talk about epic timing!!!

Answer (score 4):

To understand what you did wrong observe the differences in the colors between your code and mine. What do you see for the [`Sqrt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html) function? Something is different.

Something is also different for the variable `k`. Have a close look.

There rest is fine. See the below:

```
f[k_] := -(1/2)^k - ((1/4) (1 - Sqrt[5]))^k/
   Sqrt[5] + ((1/4) (1 + Sqrt[5]))^k/Sqrt[5]

Array[f, 15];

ListPlot[%, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]
```

[image: array]

Comment: The time only ` 0:01` difference.

Comment: @cvgmt hahahaha yes. I also left a message, but deleted because people say we shouldn't write funny stuff, etc :-) I should have left it!!!